# Version Number Plugin in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use version number plugin to format a version number for our 
packages. 
From some reason the placement for the version variable doesn't work
and when I echo the following I only get the build number, for instance: "...54"

```
    def Version_Major = '1'
    def Version_Minor  = '0'
    def Version_Patch  = '0'

    pipeline {  
        environment {
          VERSION = VersionNumber([
              versionNumberString: '${Version_Major}.${Version_Minor}.${Version_Patch}.${BUILD_NUMBER}', 
           worstResultForIncrement: 'SUCCESS'

          ]);
        }
            stage ('Restore packages'){
            steps {
                script{
                echo "${VERSION}"
             }
          }
       }
   }
```

Edit: It does look like an issue with the plugin usage since this works:

```
properties([
    parameters([        
        string(name: 'Version_Major', defaultValue: '1', description: 'Version Major'),
        string(name: 'Version_Minor', defaultValue: '0', description: 'Version Minor'),
        string(name: 'Version_Patch', defaultValue: '0', description: 'Version Patch')
        ])
    ])

pipeline {  
    agent any
    environment {
     VERSION = "${params.Version_Major}.${params.Version_Minor}.${params.Version_Patch}.${BUILD_NUMBER}"
    }

    stages{
    stage ('Test'){
        steps {     
            echo "${VERSION}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would using double quotes work better? `versionNumberString: "${Version_Major}..."`

Comment: No, just adds quotes to the printed message.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the variables inside the pipeline.

Try this:

```
pipeline {  
    environment {
      Version_Major = '1'
      Version_Minor  = '0'
      Version_Patch  = '0'
      VERSION = VersionNumber([
          versionNumberString: '${Version_Major}.${Version_Minor}.${Version_Patch}.${BUILD_NUMBER}', 
       worstResultForIncrement: 'SUCCESS'

      ]);
    }
        stage ('Restore packages'){
        steps {
            script{
            echo "${VERSION}"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you need to use a parameter instead that's also possible via:

```
parameters {
        string(name: 'PERSON', defaultValue: 'Mr Jenkins', description: 'Who should I say hello to?')
    }
```

usage:
`"Hello ${params.PERSON}"`

Comment: Unfortunately both doesn't work for me and resulting the same outcome. It looks like the version plugin doesn't concat the versions argument from some reason.

Comment: There's no error, or stack trace. The build passes only with the wrong output.